# Rails 4: strong parameter with variable key hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, parameter-passing, strong-parameters

I need to be able to permit parameters that contain a `hash` with a variable key.  I've looked at other solutions but none seem to work for me.

The parameters are as follows:

```
{"consult_stat"=>{"iter_0"=>{"employee_id"=>"1", "consults"=>"10", "signed"=>"11"}, "iter_1"=>{"employee_id"=>"1", "consults"=>"10", "signed"=>"11"}, "iter_2"=>{"employee_id"=>"1", "consults"=>"10", "signed"=>"11"}}
```

...where the number of `iter_x` parameters changes.  I can hard code for a few iterations (seen below) but I'd like a more flexible solution that changes the permitted params based on the parameters provided.  The following works up to a `iter_5`.

```
params.require(:consult_stat).permit(:revenue, :weeks, :weeks_paid_up_front, :additional_weeks, :extensions, :paid_in_full, iter_0: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ], iter_1: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ], iter_2: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ], iter_3: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ], iter_4: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ], iter_5: [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strong params method is just ruby, you don't have to provide a literal hash as the argument to `permit`, you can provide a hash that you create based on the *"iter_"* keys present in `params`:

```
iter_array = [ :employee_id, :signed, :consults ]
p = params.require(:consult_stat)
p.permit(
  :revenue,
  :weeks,
  :weeks_paid_up_front,
  :additional_weeks,
  :extensions,
  :paid_in_full,
  Hash[p.keys.grep(/^iter_\d+$/).map {|k| [k.to_sym, iter_array] }]
)
```

Comment: Amazing.  I wasted so much time trying to get this to work.  I think it's time I learn regex.  Been avoiding it for too long

Answer (score 0):

You can do this and it will work. But you need to be careful about the values.

> params.require(:consult_stat).permit!

It will permit the hash consult_stat and any subhashes of it.

Comment: You have a typo there. It should be `permit!`.

Comment: But isnt that unsafe?

Comment: Yeah it is. You can create a parent hash  and usee permit on it and it is the only way.